# Recursive Fibonacci in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, fibonacci

This week is my first time doing recursion. One of the problems I was able to solve was Fibonacci's sequence to the nth number; it wasn't hard after messing with it for 5 minutes.

However, I am having trouble understanding why this works with the current return statement.

```
return array if num == 2
```

If I push to array, it doesn't work, if I make a new variable sequence and push to that, it returns the correct answer. I am cool with that, but my base case says return array, not sequence. I initially pushed the sequence to the array, the result was not fibs sequence. I only solved the problem when I tried seeing what would happen if I pushed to the sequence array.

Instead of just making it work I was hoping someone could explain what was happening under the hood, what the stacks might be and how the problem works.

I understand recursion to an extent and somehow intuitively can make it work by assuming things, but I feel funny not actually knowing all the whys behind it.

```
def fib_seq(num)
  return [0] if num == 1
  return [] if num == 0

  array = [0, 1]
  return array if num <= 2 

  seq = fib_seq(num - 1)  
  seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code can be simplified a bit by removing the temporary `array` variable. It's a distraction. It also only applies when `num == 2`; `num < 2` will be handled by the other base cases. `num < 0` is illegal and should be handled by an error check.

I've also added in an explicit return. Explicit returns make it very obvious what's being returned and that helps understand recursion. In this case it's `seq`. ("*Explicit returns are evil!*" all the Ruby style people cry. Tough cookies. Good style isn't an absolute.)

```
def fib_seq(num)
  # Error check
  if num < 0 then
      raise ArgumentError, "The number must be a positive integer"
  end

  # Terminating base cases
  return [] if num == 0
  return [0] if num == 1
  return [0,1] if num == 2 

  # Recursion
  seq = fib_seq(num - 1) 

  # The recursive function
  seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]

  return seq
end
```

Now it's a bit clearer that `return [0,1] if num == 2` is one of three *base cases* for the recursion. These are the terminating conditions which stops the recursion. But processing doesn't end there. The result isn't `[0,1]` because after that first return the stack has to unwind.

Let's walk through `fib_seq(4)`.

```
fib_seq(4) calls fib_seq(3)
fib_seq(3) calls fib_seq(2)
fib_seq(2) returns `[0,1]`
```

We've reached the base case, now we need to unwind that stack of calls.

The call to `fib_seq(3)` picks up where it left off. `seq` returned from `fib_seq(2)` is `[0,1]`. It adds `seq[-2] + seq[-1]` onto the end and returns `[0,1,1]`.

`fib_seq(4)` picks up where it left off. `seq` returned from `fib_seq(3)` is `[0,1,1]`. It adds `seq[-2] + seq[-1]` to the end and returns `[0,1,1,2]`.

The stack is unwound, so we get back `[0,1,1,2]`.

As you can see, the actual calculation happens backwards. `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)` and `f(2) = [0,1]`. It recurses down to `f(2)`, the base case, then unwinds back up doing `f(3)` using the result of `f(2)`, and `f(4)` using the result of `f(3)` and so on.

Comment: I've written 5 more recursive functions after reading this. That stack trace completely clicked and got me through a few problems I didn't understand earlier. Now onto binary search and merge sort!

Answer (score 2):

Recursive functions need to have an *exit condition* to prevent them from running forever. The main part of your recursive method is the following:

```
seq = fib_seq(num - 1)
seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]
```

In Ruby, the last expression of a method is considered to be the return value of that method, so the lines above are equivalent to:

```
seq = fib_seq(num - 1)
seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]
return seq
```

Let's run down what would happen if the method only contained these two lines, with *num* = 4:

```
call fib_seq(4)
  call fib_seq(3)
    call fib_seq(2)
      call fib_seq(1)
        call fib_seq(0)
          call fib_seq(-1)
            ...
```

Obviously this results in an infinite loop, since we have no exit condition. We always call `fib_seq` again on the first line, so the code has no chance of ever reaching the `return` statement at the end. To fix the problem, let's add in these two lines at the beginning:

```
array = [0, 1]
return array if num <= 2
```

These can be simplified down to just:

```
return [0, 1] if num <= 2
```

Now let's see what happens when we call the method with *num* = 4:

```
call fib_seq(4)
  4 > 2, exit condition not triggered, calling fib_seq(n - 1)
  call fib_seq(3)
    3 > 2, exit condition not triggered, calling fib_seq(n - 1)
    call fib_seq(2)
    2 == 2, exit condition triggered, returning [0, 1]!
  fib_seq(2) returned with seq = [0, 1]
  add 0 + 1 together, push new value to seq
  seq is now [0, 1, 1]
  return seq
fib_seq(3) returned with seq = [0, 1, 1]
add 1 + 1 together, push new value to seq
seq is now [0, 1, 1, 2]
return seq
FINAL RESULT: [0, 1, 1, 2]
```

So it looks like this method is working for values of *num* that are >= 2:

```
def fib_seq(num)
  return [0, 1] if num <= 2

  seq = fib_seq(num - 1)
  seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]
end
```

There is one bug left: *num* = 0 and *num* = 1 both return `[0, 1]`. Let's fix that:

```
def fib_seq(num)
  return [] if num == 0
  return [0] if num == 1
  return [0, 1] if num == 2

  seq = fib_seq(num - 1)
  seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]
end
```

Clean it up a little:

```
def fib_seq(num)
  return [0, 1].first(num) if num <= 2
  seq = fib_seq(num - 1)
  seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I always find it confusing when people mix imperative style mutations with functional style recursion – if you're going to do all reassignment and manual array seeking, why bother with using recursion as the looping mechanism? just use a loop.

That's not to say this program can't be expressed in a more functional way, tho. Here, we separate concerns of computing fibonacci numbers and generating a sequence – the result is an extremely easy-to-understand program

```
def fib n
  def aux m, a, b
    m == 0 ? a : aux(m - 1, b, a + b)
  end
  aux n, 0, 1
end

def fib_seq n
  (0..n).map &method(:fib)
end

fib_seq 10
#=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

And another way that's a bit more efficient for generating the sequence specifically – Below, I define an axuiliary function `aux` that utilizes 4 state variables to generate the sequence in a relatively straightforward way.

Note the difference with the input `10` - this one is closer to your proposed function where `0` returns `[]` despite [the 0<sup>th</sup> fibonacci number is actually 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

```
def fib_seq n
  def aux acc, m, a, b
    m == 0 ? acc << a : aux(acc << a, m - 1, b, a + b)
  end
  case n
    when 0; []
    when 1; [0]
    when 2; [0,1]
    else;   aux [0,1], n - 3, 1, 2
  end
end

fib_seq 10
# => [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```